# How can I reset the viewport of my React-Flow project to fitView, without clicking the Controls fitView?

Tags: react-flow

I'm working on a React-Flow project. I'm changing the layout of the nodes and edges with a button and I want the last thing to happen to be resetting the viewport to be centered (so just fitView).

How can I do this?

I've tried calling fitView() again but this doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `fitView` inside of a `setTimeout`

```js
setTimeout(reactFlowInstance.setView)
```

There is no need to pass a specific delay to the timeout, since ([quoting the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)):

> If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, the next event cycle.

Which in our case is following the re-render of the Flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `fitView()` on the react flow instance.

The instance you get from the onInit callback and save in a state, e.g. like this:

```
<ReactFlow ... onInit={(instance) => setReactFlowInstance(instance)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this pattern on the official documentation

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => fitView());
```